# fusioncharts: Line graph is giving errors

Tags: graph, charts, fusioncharts

Iam able to draw graphs like "Column2D, Column3D, Bar2D, Bar3D, Funnel etc, but Iam unable to draw graphs of "Line" and "MsLine". Following is my javascript code :

```
jQuery('#myChartContainer').insertFusionCharts({
swfPath: base_url+'resource/js/Charts/',
width : '400',
height: '500',
type: "MSLine",
chartRightMargin: '20', 
                                    data:                                         "<graph caption='Monthly Sales Summary' 
          subcaption='For the year 2004' 
          xAxisName='Month' 
          yAxisMinValue='15000' 
          yAxisName='Sales' 
          numberPrefix='$' 
          showNames='1' 
          showValues='0' 
          rotateNames='0' 
          showColumnShadow='1' 
          animation='1' 
          showAlternateHGridColor='1' 
          AlternateHGridColor='ff5904' 
          divLineColor='ff5904' 
          divLineAlpha='20' 
          alternateHGridAlpha='5' 
          canvasBorderColor='666666' 
          baseFontColor='666666'>
          <set name='Jan' value='17400' hoverText='January'/>
          <set name='Feb' value='19800' hoverText='February'/>
          <set name='Mar' value='21800' hoverText='March'/>
          <set name='Apr' value='23800' hoverText='April'/>
          <set name='May' value='29600' hoverText='May'/>
          <set name='Jun' value='27600' hoverText='June'/>
          <set name='Jul' value='31800' hoverText='July'/>
          <set name='Aug' value='39700' hoverText='August'/>
          <set name='Sep' value='37800' hoverText='September'/>
          <set name='Oct' value='21900' hoverText='October'/>
          <set name='Nov' value='32900' hoverText='November' />
          <set name='Dec' value='39800' hoverText='December' />
          </graph>",
     dataFormat: "XMLData",
     wMode: "transparent"
});
```

When I use, Line/MSLine graphs, I get following error in FIREBIG :

"uncaught exception: Chart Type Not Found!"

But when I check swf files on server, I can see LINE and MSLINE swfs, along with other graph swfs like COLUMNS2S, COLUMN3D, FUNNEL etc.

Can some one guide me where and what Iam doing wrong and how it can be rectified.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hi,my guess is that XML data posted in the question is bot proper and might not also work for other charts. Still I would love to check out your code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you been able to successfuly plot any charts?

I'm also not convinced your XML is valid. Please see the [FusionCharts Support Forum](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_id=2424) for the relevant XSDs. I haven't created FusionCharts usign JavaScript before but the following is valid xml:

```
<chart>
<categories>
<category label='Jan'> 
<category label='Feb'>
<category label='Mar'>
<category label='Apr'>
<category label='May'>
<category label='Jun'>
<category label='Jul'>
<category label='Aug'>
<category label='Sep'>
<category label='Oct'>
<category label='Nov'>
<category label='Dec'>
</categories>
<dataset>
<set value='17400' hoverText='January'/>
<set value='19800' hoverText='February'/>
<set value='21800' hoverText='March'/>
<set value='23800' hoverText='April'/>
<set value='29600' hoverText='May'/>
<set value='27600' hoverText='June'/>
<set value='31800' hoverText='July'/>
<set value='39700' hoverText='August'/>
<set value='37800' hoverText='September'/>
<set value='21900' hoverText='October'/>
<set value='32900' hoverText='November' />
<set value='39800' hoverText='December' />
</dataset>
</chart>
```

Comment: If you are using FusionCharts FREE `<chart>` won't work. You need to use `<graph>`. Again, `label` attribute needs to be replaced by `name` attribute. `HoverText` is not supported in `<set>` element of MultiSeries charts. It is advisable to add a `seriesName` in `<dataset>`. Reference: http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/Docs/

Answer (score 0):

Please try once using the name `line2d` and `msline2d`.

Here is the list of acceptable chart types:

```
        area2d
        bar2d
        bubble
        candlestick
        column2d
        column3d
        donut2d
        donut3d
        doughnut2d
        doughnut3d
        dragarea
        dragcolumn2d
        dragline
        dragnode
        drawingpad
        errorbar2D
        exportcomponent
        funnel
        gantt
        horizontalbullet
        inversearea2d
        inversecolumn2d
        inverseline2d
        kagi
        line2d
        logcolumn2d
        logline2d
        msarea2d
        msbar2d
        msbar3d
        mscolumn2d
        mscolumn3d
        mscolumn3dline
        mscolumn3dlinedy
        mscombi2d
        mscombi3d
        mscombidy2d
        msline2d
        msspline2d
        mssplinearea2d
        msstackedcolumn2d
        msstackedcolumn2dlinedy
        multiaxisline
        multilevelpie
        pie2d
        pie3d
        pyramid
        radar
        realtimeangular
        realtimearea
        realtimebulb
        realtimecolumn
        realtimecylinder
        realtimehorizontalled
        realtimehorizontallinear
        realtimeline
        realtimestackedarea
        realtimestackedcolumn
        realtimethermometer
        realtimeverticalled
        scatter
        scrollarea2d
        scrollcolumn2d
        scrollcombi2d
        scrollcombidy2d
        scrollline2d
        scrollstackedcolumn2d
        selectscatter
        sparkcolumn
        sparkline
        sparkwinloss
        spline2d
        splinearea2d
        ssgrid
        stackedarea2d
        stackedbar2d
        stackedbar3d
        stackedcolumn2d
        stackedcolumn3d
        stackedcolumn3dlinedy
        verticalbullet
        waterfall
```